# How to get session ID in sql in joomla

Tags: sql, joomla

I'm working with vcharts in Joomla and trying tom implement charts based on who is logged in. Sadly vcharts only allows me to use SQL for queries and not PHP so How will I get the session ID then.

Comment: Also posted here: https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=715&p=3582478  When you have Joomla questions, please check/post at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: funny enough thats my question on there I want to have a look at the documentation but my employer has yet to provide me with credentials to do so

Comment: Yes, I made the connection with `Was` and the time of the post.  The Plotalot extension has great documention and is very clear about these necessary constants that can be fed to queries.

Comment: Thank you for your help I will have to ask my supervisor if she's ok with buying a whole new library.... you know a one that doesn't hide their documentation behind a paywall...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the SO question [Variables added to vchart joomla sql query not picked up](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58121940/2943403) (that exposes a relevant portion of the vcharts manual which joomla users must ordinarily pay to see...) it seems the placeholder that you can use in your SQL is:

```
{loggedinuserid}
```

So, you might write something like

```
SELECT * FROM #__users WHERE id = {loggedinuserid}
```

Of course this is just a guess because I've never used vcharts, nor have I seen the actual docs.

If it doesn't like the `#__` prefix placeholder, then I guess you'll need to manually replace it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM lmnop_users WHERE id = {loggedinuserid}
```

All this said, I have had some experience with the Plotalot extension and it's pretty good with great documentation.

Comment: I tried it sadly vchart doesn't recognize it and I suggested Plotalot to my supervisor but were too far gone at this point

Comment: right now the solution im working with is to use the joomla made db to get last user using encrypted key

Comment: That doesn't sound reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I find this approach: with joomla api

```
<?php
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "joomla_usr", "geheim", "joomla_db");
    define('_JEXEC', 1);
    define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__));
    define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    require_once(JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'defines.php');
    require_once(JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'framework.php');
    require('libraries/joomla/factory.php');
    $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
    $mainframe->initialise();
    $session = JFactory::getSession();
    $query_user = "SELECT name, username, email FROM joomla_users WHERE id=(SELECT userid FROM joomla_session WHERE session_id='" . $session->getId() . "')";
        $result_user = mysqli_query($link, $query_user);
        $row_user = mysqli_fetch_array($result_user);
 ?>
```

Maybe you can use the query direct to access the mysql database from your Platform. Or embed PHP in any way.

Comment: The solution needs to be pure sql.  There will need to be a constant (defined by the joomla extension developer) which must be used.  I could not research because the documentation is only viewable for paying customers.